# Can I pass more than one instance of a Model to a controller in the same form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC View that posts several Models back to a controller. I have a requirement to add the ability to allow a user to add X number of "Infractions" from the same form. What I want to do can be compared to posting back an IEnumerable of the "Infractions" object to the controller. If there were some way to do this it would be great:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<Infractions> infractions)
```

I would then iterate the IEnumerable and add the infractions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible.  See [Phil Haack's post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) on this issue here.

The trick is to render the initial get property names in the correct format so the model binder recognize it as a list/array.

For example:

```
<input type='text' name='[0].Property1OnInfractions' />
<input type='text' name='[0].Property2OnInfractions' />

<input type='text' name='[1].Property1OnInfractions' />
<input type='text' name='[1].Property2OnInfractions' />
```

In your case you have to convert your IEnumerable to IList to get the following to  work:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Property1OnInfractions)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Property2OnInfractions)
}
```

And action signature should look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<Infractions> infractions)
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to have the signature as: `public ActionResult Create(IList<Infractions> infractions)` ?

Comment: @jimtollan, the original code had it even more more generic as `IEnumerable` which still works on the HttpPost but someone has edit my answer to `List` :(